# using today date in Database.getQueryLocator query String throwing errors

Tags: apex, batch, date, dynamic-soql, querystrings

I am running a batch class. I am providing query in string format. I am facing issue with using a filter criteria
StartDate__c>=:System.today()

In a direct query, i could write something like

```
List<Contact> allContacts = [Select Id from Contact where StartDate__c>=:System.Today()];
```

But in start method of batch job, i am writing this

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
      String todayDate = System.today().format();
      String queryString = 'Select Id from Contact where StartDate__c>='+todayDate;
      return Database.getQueryLocator(queryString);
}
```

unfortunately, i am getting error - unexpected token: /

I believe the start date in string format is coming out to be 5/8/2021 and when it is concatenated to querystring, that / is causing issues. Anyway i can escape it?

Or for that matter, is there a better way to put that where clause for a date field while using String query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're actually using dynamic queries (variable fields or filters), you should use inline queries.

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([
    Select Id from Contact where StartDate__c>=today
]);
```

As Reuben said, you can use [date literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) like "today".

I've left a doc bug to have them fix the documentation to include examples of inline queries; they are recommended and preferred when you do not need dynamic field lists or a variable number of conditions.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [date literal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) `TODAY`:
`SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE StartDate__c >= TODAY`.

You could also store `System.today()` in a `Date` variable, then [bind it](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm):

```
Date today = System.today();
String queryString = 'SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE StartDate__c >= :today';
return Database.getQueryLocator(queryString);
```

Variables binding should be the preferred way to add parameters to a query string.

Answer (score 0):

The format you want is `YYYY-MM-DD`, so

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
      String todayDate = System.today().year() + '-' + System.today().month() 
                         + '-' + system.today().day();
      String queryString = 'Select Id from Contact where StartDate__c>='+todayDate;
      return Database.getQueryLocator(queryString);
}
```